# JSON Data with Plyr Player

Tags: javascript, plyr.js

Hello I have a `php` code which shows a `json` file with video `url`. I want to use that `url` in `plyr` player.

When click the link https://example.com/test.php

It shows the output file as `json` which is:

```
[{"label":"Original","file":"https://example.com.mp4","type":"video\/mp4"}]
```

I want to use that data with `javascript` and open it in `plyr` player. Some `javascript` code from `plyr` player. I really do not know what to do with it.

```html
<video id="player" playsinline controls>
</video>
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.6.4/plyr.js"></script>
<script>
  const player = new Plyr('#player');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the data (here, I use `fetch`) and `then` (it is an `async` function) set the video source `data`:

```js
const player = new Plyr('#player');
fetch('https://example.com/test.php')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then( data => {
    player.source = {
      type: 'video',
      title: data[0].label,
      sources: [
        {
          src: data[0].file,
          type: data[0].type,
          size: 720,
        },
      ],
      /*
         You can add extra info to the player:

      poster: '/path/to/poster.jpg',
      previewThumbnails: {
        src: '/path/to/thumbnails.vtt',
      },
      tracks: [
        {
          kind: 'captions',
          label: 'English',
          srclang: 'en',
          src: '/path/to/captions.en.vtt',
          default: true,
        },
        {
          kind: 'captions',
          label: 'French',
          srclang: 'fr',
          src: '/path/to/captions.fr.vtt',
        },
      ],
      */
    };
})
```

**Note:** You'll probably want to handle `fetch` errors (outside the scope of this question).